# how to write into a dictionary from a file?

Tags: python

Hi my assignment is to read the company names and the shorten names of the companies

In `def name_to_symbol(companyname, tickerdict)`
I cant get the companyname variable and the tickerdict variable, i dont know why can someone help me

pe_8_4_tickers.txt

```
YAHOO:YHOO
GOOGLE INC:GOOG
Harley-Davidson:HOG
Yamana Gold:AUY
Sotheby's:BID
inBev:BUD
```

```
f = open('pe_8_4_tickers.txt', 'r')
file = f.readlines()
ticker_dict = {}
f.close()

def tickers_to_dict(file):
    for line in file:
        line_sepperated = line.split(':')
        companyname = line_sepperated[0]
        symbol = line_sepperated[1]
        ticker_dict[line_sepperated[0]] = line_sepperated[1]
    return companyname, symbol, ticker_dict

def name_to_symbol(companyname, ticker_dict):
    tickers_to_dict(file)
    ticker_dict = {}
# the assesment has one more def statement but i couldnt reach there

name_to_symbol(symbol, ticker_dict)
```

output i expect:

```
Enter Company name: YAHOO
Ticker symbol: YHOO
```

Enter Ticker symbol: BUD
Company name: inBev

Comment: do you want to get ticker_dict filled or do you want to get company symbol as return of name_to_symbol?

Comment: Can you please update the question to show the output you expect?

Comment: okay one second

Comment: It does not look like you ever call those functions that you have implemented - if they behave not as expected please provide the actual code where you call them and get an error, if any, along with error messages or description of the wrong behavior.

Comment: You haven't told us much beyond *this code doesn't work.* That's not enough to go on. What output are you expecting, and how does this differ from what you are getting? I *think* you might want to do `_, _, ticker_dict = tickers_to_dict(file)` instead of `ticker_dict = {}` but that is just a guess. If you get an error message please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('pe_8_4_tickers.txt', 'r')
file = f.readlines()
f.close()

def tickers_to_dict(file):
    for line in file:
        line_sepperated = line.split(':')
        companyname = line_sepperated[0]
        symbol = line_sepperated[1]
        ret_dict[line_sepperated[0]] = line_sepperated[1]
    return ret_dict

def name_to_symbol(companyname):
    ticker_dict=tickers_to_dict(file)
    return ticker_dict[companyname]
# the assesment has one more def statement but i couldnt reach there

name_to_symbol(symbol)
```

returns the result you expected. But it will read from file every time when you call a company. So if you want to read file once you need to call **tickers_to_dict** function in somewhere else rather than in **name_to_symbol**

Comment: Abi, i still cant recieve the company name :(

Comment: are you trying to get company name from company slug or company slug from company name?

Answer (score 1):

You're (a) returning the global variable `ticker_dict` out of `tickers_to_dict`; (b) shadowing the global variable `ticker_dict` with an argument in `name_to_symbol`, and (c) setting `ticker_dict` to `{}` after you've read it.

You're also calling `name_to_symbol` with a symbol, even though company name is expected.

In addition, (a) you don't need the `readlines()` call (you can directly use a file in a `for` loop); (b) for splitting up the lines, it's better to use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) rather than doing it manually (unless your assignment specifically forbids this); (c) use a `with` statement to make sure the file is closed even if an exception is raised; and (d) it's better not to do much at the top level of a script, instead put everything into functions.

```
def tickers_to_dict(file):
    result = {}
    for companyname, symbol in csv.reader(file, delimiter=':'):
        result[companyname] = symbol
    return result

def name_to_symbol(companyname, ticker_dict):
    ...

def main():
    with open('pe_8_4_tickers.txt', 'r') as f:
        ticker_dict = tickers_to_dict(f)

    ... get company name from user ...
    symbol = name_to_symbol(companyname, ticker_dict)
    ... show result to user ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```